# AJAX update on POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a change of password using AJAX and POST

Normally I can make it work fine, and if the change of password is complete and error free, it returns just a blank white page (This is without Ajax) I am trying to make the entire change of password, happen in a small div, which will then update with the response (either successfuly or not successful)

I have cut much of the code down so I can eliminate possible issues:

```
<div id="s-window">
    <form id="changepassword" action="changePassword.php" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="currentPassword" placeholder="Current Password"/>
        <input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password"/>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Change Password" />
    </form>
</div>
```

changePassword.php:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $currentPassword = ($_POST['currentPassword']); 
    $password = ($_POST['newPassword']);
    $password2 = ($_POST['confirmPassword']);
    $username = ($_SESSION['username']);

    if ($password <> $password2) 
    { 
        echo "Your passwords do not match.";
    }
    else if ($password === $password2) 
    {
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = "UPDATE Staff SET password='$hashed_password' WHERE username='$username'";
        mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    { 
        mysqli_error($con); 
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I know the MySQL stuff is messy - it's something I am going to work on.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "changePassword.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){ // this happens after we get results
            $("#s-window").append(html);
        }
    });
};
```

I have no experience with jQuery and my googling has not yielded any sufficiently similar results that I could build from.

Comment: You do not set any `data` to be sent with the request

Comment: What does that mean? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: To familiarize yourself with the method you are trying to use, I can recommend the [official API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I have the API page open. There is far too much information there for it to be useful. I dont know which of those are required, which are extra, Its like needing a glass of water and having someone hand you a swimming pool.

Comment: The only parameter that's required is `url` the rest are all optional as they have default values.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get a blank white page is because the `form` element `submit` event is still firing after the `button` has been clicked. To prevent this, a better pattern to use is to hook your code to that `submit` event instead of the button click. Try this:

```
$("#changepassword").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop normal form submission
    $.ajax({
        url: "changePassword.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(), // you also need to send the form data
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#s-window").append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that your PHP code only returns a string value when there is a mis-match in the provided passwords. You may wish to change that behaviour so that the end user knows when the action has been completed successfully too.

Comment: Actually sending the data would be nice too :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, can't see the woods for the trees today :D

Comment: I can't even see the trees today! :) +1

Comment: It is still returning the blank white page. I was hoping to just have that div update and not refresh the entire page.

Comment: This code should do that for you. Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: The only errors I have are alot of Deprecated: mysql_connect(): errors. It still completes the funtction properly. But it moves me from my page I am on, to the changePassword.php page rather than just running the changePassword.php page inside the main page.

Comment: Do I need to modify my html at all? Add or remove something from the <form> tags?

Comment: Not at all, it should work as is. Those errors look PHP related. When I mentioned the console I meant the in browser one, by pressing F12.

Comment: Ah Yes, here Uncaught 
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; 
And it is referencing this:
}; 
Which is the very last closing brace on the code you gave me.

Comment: Still not working properly. There are no more errors on the console but it is still redirecting rather than updating in page. Can I give you any more information to help you figure this out? I dont have enough reputation to take this to chat so I dont know how better to work on this.

Comment: Anything anyone can suggest to try would be great. Even if its just a walkthrough for ajax/jquery ect.

Answer (score 0):

with the result in the `changepassword.php` page
then echo the output as "updated" or "notupdated" in one variable

in response you can add a check 
with the resp
in the success function 
lke this

```
    if(resp=='updated')
{
alert('password has been updated');
}
if(resp=='notupdated')
{
alert('password not updated,plz try again');
}
```

hope this helps...

Comment: JSON datatype is not required. It may be more semantic, but it's certainly not required, and it's not going to affect the immediate issue of the redirect on form submission.

Comment: i agree with you jus a simple varible can be declared in changepassword.php page on updating the password will help to check whether it is updated or not - Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues.
1. you need to change button type submit to button. Because button type submit always submit you form.
2. Javascript code will be as :

$(".button").click(function(){

```
        var str = $( "#changepassword" ).serialize();

      $.ajax({

url: "changePassword.php",
type: "POST",
dataType: "html",
 data: str,
success: function(html){ // this happens after we get results

  $("#s-window").append(html);
}
```

});
      })

3. You are not printing any value in changePassword.php file. The information you want to show after successful login you should print on changePassword.php file.
   Hope this help you